# Mapping an array into objects with odd elements as keys and even elements as values

Tags: javascript, arrays

The title should be pretty self explanatory. How can I turn the following array :

```
[
  "Bargain",
  "deal",
  "Consistent",
  "Steady; regular",
  "Accurately",
  "a thing bought or offered for sale much more cheaply than is usual or expected.",
  "Charge",
  "demand (an amount) as a price for a service rendered or goods supplied."
]
```

Into the below array :

```
[
    {"Bargain": "deal"},
    {"Consistent": "Steady; regular"},
    {"Accurately": "a thing bought or offered for sale much more cheaply than is usual or expected."},
    {"Charge": "demand (an amount) as a price for a service rendered or goods supplied."}
]
```

The solution might be simple but I can't figure out a simple way to achieve it. I tried making 2 separate arrays and filtering the elements of each array by taking out the odd values in the first one and the even values in the second before merging them after but that seems like an overkill.

Is there a simple way to achieve it ?

(Yes, I am aware that the definition for 'Accurately' is... weird)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can do that with a simple `for` loop :

```js
const data = [
  "Bargain",
  "deal",
  "Consistent",
  "Steady; regular",
  "Accurately",
  "a thing bought or offered for sale much more cheaply than is usual or expected.",
  "Charge",
  "demand (an amount) as a price for a service rendered or goods supplied."
];

let result = [];

for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i += 2) {
  result.push({
    [data[i]]: data[i + 1]
  });
}

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use [`Array.from`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) like this:

```js
const input = [
  "Bargain",
  "deal",
  "Consistent",
  "Steady; regular",
  "Accurately",
  "a thing bought or offered for sale much more cheaply than is usual or expected.",
  "Charge",
  "demand (an amount) as a price for a service rendered or goods supplied."
]

const length = Math.ceil(input.length / 2)

const output = Array.from({ length }, (_, i) =>
   ({ [input[i*2]]: input[i*2+1] })
  );
  
console.log(output)
```